# Ajax dynamic navigation

Tags: ajax, dynamic, navigation, load

Hello and happy New Year everyone :)

I'm not a boss in Ajax and I've got a little problem I can't solve.

I've got a page which contains a dynamic navigation with ajax, I've got multiple php files I can load with.

here's my navigation in this page

```
<section id="sub-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="little-button" id="ajax-media">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="little-button" id="ajax-business">Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="little-button" id="ajax-events">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="little-button" id="ajax-music-business">Music Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="little-button" id="ajax-institutions">Institutions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Each button call a page like this

```
$('#ajax-media').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#solution-wrapper').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $('#solution-wrapper').load('../solution-media.php', function(){
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
      });
    });
  });
```

I would like to rewrite the url's when I change my content, and I want to access the content directly when I parse the url in my browser.

Could you guys can help me to begin a perfect new year without too many problems in my code?
How can I do these things?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: If this is for SEO reasons, I would suggest to just make it first work without the ajax (e.g. regular links in your navigation), and afterwards create the javascript to take over the click (unobtrusive javascript)

Comment: Reinder is right. What you could do is have a single file with all the content and have an anchor for each section, that way  it'll automatically take you to that section as well

Comment: Yes it would be easier in a single file but for SEO it would be better in multiple pages I think. And to load pages dynamically I don't know how to do it without Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy New Year

When you say rewrite url what kind of format do you want? Example: Do you want it to say http://example.com/solution-media.php?

it'd be easiest using # so example.com/index.php#media where index.php is the container website.

If you want you can rewrite the url server-side to get rid of index.php and then you'd get /media (using html5 history api built in into anything modern)

the # example is below

```
$('#ajax-media').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#solution-wrapper').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $('#solution-wrapper').load('../solution-media.php', function(){

   $(this).fadeIn('slow');
   window.location.hash = 'media'; // This is the line that gives you the #
      });
    });
  });
```

Let me know if this makes sense

if you want to be able to paste the url and load that section here's a rough idea of how that can be done (off the top of my head)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var section = window.location.hash;

if (section) {
$('#ajax-'+section).trigger('click')
}

});
```

Comment: this will not take care of the 2nd requirement which is 'access the content directly when I parse the url in my browser'...

Comment: yes, you're correct. for that he'd need to grab the #part on load and trigger appropriate ajax call. Just wanted to make sure we're on the same page. because if he wants the big php url to show then he'll still be making a full reload.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I've already tried to use window.location.hash but I can't access to it if I parse this URL.

Also I've got a navigation on my homepage with different links and I want to directly access to the right content by clicking on a link from this page.

Comment: What do you mean you can't access it if you parse the URL. for the second part see my edit, it's possible to fully support going to that section. I've done it in the past. Let me put together a simple demo

Comment: Sorry I meant "Paste" the url. With that, the URL will change but if, for example, I give you the right URL to the content "mypage.html/content2.php" you will arrive on "mypage.html". I would like that when I give URL to someone, it's possible to directly see the content.

Comment: yes if you copy that link http://198.144.180.137/hash-example/#business it will take you straight there it's index.php and goes to business section automatically

Comment: After looking at your example I have finally succeeded to make it work, thank you very much :)